# RosAria ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out

Tags: ros, pioneer, rosaria, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am working with Pioneer 3DX and using RosAria library to control the robot. The rosaria library was working fine. But suddenly today I encountered this problem and I am not able to solve. On running rosaria rode using 'rosrun rosaria RosAria' I face the following serial error. I have set full permissions for my serial port.

```
ramkumar@ramkumar-Inspiron-7720:~$ rosrun rosaria RosAria rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0
[ INFO] [1422207128.792943336]: RosAria: using port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
Syncing 0
Syncing 1
Syncing 2
Connected to robot.
Name: IIT-madras_3906
Type: Pioneer
Subtype: p3dx-sh
ArConfig: Config version: 2.0
Loaded robot parameters from p3dx-sh.p
ArRobotPacketReceiver::receivePacket: bad packet, bad checksum
ArRobotConnector: Connecting to MTX batteries (if neccesary)...
ArRobotConnector: Connecting to MTX sonar (if neccesary)...
[ INFO] [1422207129.572967595]: Setting TicksMM from ROS Parameter: 128
[ INFO] [1422207129.575718946]: Setting DriftFactor from ROS Parameter: 0
[ INFO] [1422207129.577907662]: Setting RevCount from ROS Parameter: 16570
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 1002 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
[ INFO] [1422207129.817593371]: RosAria: publishing new recharge state 0.
[ INFO] [1422207129.817769667]: RosAria: publishing new motors state 0.
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 1203 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 1404 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 1604 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 1804 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 2004 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 2205 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 2405 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 2605 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 2805 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 3006 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 3206 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 3406 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 3606 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 3807 (201 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 4007 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 4207 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 4407 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 4607 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 4808 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 5008 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 5208 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 5408 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 5609 (201 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 5809 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 6009 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 6209 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 6409 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 6610 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 6810 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 7010 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 7210 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 7411 (201 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 7611 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 7811 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 8011 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 8212 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 8412 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 8612 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
ArRobot::myPacketReader: Timed out (4) at 8812 (200 into cycle after sleeping 200)
Losing connection because no odometry received from robot in 8058 milliseconds (greater than the timeout of 8000).
ArSerialConnection::read:  Connection invalid.
```

Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201708/rosaria-arrobot::mypacketreader:-timed-out/) by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2015-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error message indicates that ARIA is not receiving data from the robot, even though it was able to do the initial connection.   Start by checking physical connection to the robot and any settings related to /dev/ttyUSB0.  Also make sure that no other software is attempting to use or change parameters of that port.   Have you made any changes to rosaria?  Are any  clients connecting to the RosAria node or is this the result of running the RosAria node only?

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-01-26**:
I got this problem fixed. I had mounted my robot over a deck for testing purpose and that was causing the problem. Pioneer is designed to make an initial jerk that works as a feedback mechanism (syncing 0 1 2).  B4 8058ms u need to make a small jerk rotating a wheel manually, it solves the problem.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2015-01-27**:
Glad it is now working.  What do you mean by deck, and by jerk?   You should not ned to manually move the wheels or robot for communications to continue, if so there is something wrong with its controller, encoders or similar.